# Determin size of Graphic with xslt

Tags: xslt

When transforming some xml with referenced graphics I want to add a scale attribute to "big" graphics. However the graphics do not have any size information. Is it possible with xslt to "read" the graphic size in some way?

This:

```
<image href="sample.gif"/>
```

should become this

```
<image href="sample.gif" scale="50"/>
```

if the `sample.gif` graphic is bigger (width or height) than "`x`". To be able to do so I need to "read" the size of the graphic (as there are no attributes with/height values, assuming that all graphics are actually present and accessible (in the file system).

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't think that this is possible with pure XSLT** (without using an extension function).

XSLT 2.0 and above have the `unparsed-text()` function, which allows any text file to be read, but I don't think this allows any binary code (as 0x00) to be read -- the file must be a text file.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre. That's the answer I was expecting but hoping to not get. I will go for a browser based javascript calculation then.